# Custom Walker for Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I'm trying to add a custom menu structure for my WordPress theme. This is how I want it to look:

```
<li>
    <a href="link_to_parent_item" class="main-category" tabindex="3">Parent Name</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <div class="sub-links pull-left">
            <a href="link_to_child_item">Child Name1</a>
            <a href="link_to_child_item">Child Name2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've written a custom walker to do this, but it is not giving me what I really want. Here's my walker class:

```
class loggmax_class_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

// Start level, beginning tags
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $output .= "\n$indent";
    $output .= '<div class="sub-menu">';
    $output .= '<div class="sub-links pull-left">';
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $output .= "$indent</div>";
    $output .= '</div>';
}

// Start element (beginning list items)
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(),$current_object_id=0 ) {
    $this->curItem = $item;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
    $atts['slug']   = ! empty( $item->slug )        ? $item->slug      : '';
    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
    $attributes = '';
    $item_output = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    // Check if it is a submenu
    if ( $depth == 1 ) {
        $output .= '<a'. $attributes. ' >';
        $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $output .= '</a>';

    } elseif ( $depth == 0 ) {
        $item_output .= '<li>';
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes. ' class="main-category">';
        $item_output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output .= '</a>';
    }

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

and this code is in my header.php

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) )
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary-menu',
            'container'         => 'ul',
            'menu_class'        => 'pull-left',
            'items_wrap'        => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'walker'            => new loggmax_class_walker()
        ) );
```

and this is what is being displayed:

```
<li>
   <a href="link_here" class="main-category">Parent Title</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
       <div class="sub-links pull-left">
         <a href="link_here">Child Title</a></li>
         <a href="link_here">Child Title 2</a></li>
    </div>
</li>
```

How do I remove the ending list tag `</li>` that is being printed in the sub-menu items?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but you can override the `</li>` in the Walker's `end_el()` function (see wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php); in your case, something like:

```
public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $n = '';
    } else {
        $n = "\n";
    }
    if ( $depth == 0 ) {
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    } else {
        $output .= "{$n}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add CODE example to show how to do it. Only referring to WordPress core file is not enough as a good answer.

Comment: For somebody writing a custom Menu Walker (including start_el) that seems highly unnecessary to me—but there you go ;)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the

```
<li></li>
```

in the end_lvl function and also within $item_output as well. Although I have no experience with writing walker code, I have previously used a Bootstrap walker, so these might not be of any use to you. Perhaps taking a look through the following links might help?

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker
- https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Going through some WordPress documentation, I've been able to update the walker class. But the ending list tag `</li>` is still being printed in the code, at the sub-menu level. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Where is the definition of $args? The only thing I can think of is your using $args->link_before and $args->link_after. I can't see where it is defined in the code.

Comment: You're correct @EBennett. I've updated the code, but the ending list tag `</li>` is still being printed in sub-menu items.